# How can I find a drive specified by a ID_VENDOR_ID:ID_MODEL_ID more easily?

Tags: linux, udev, devices

I'm using virt-manager and I am trying to select a USB device. It's telling me some valuable device information:

[image]

but I don't know where to find that other than using:

```
udevadm info --query=all --name=/dev/sde | grep 058f
E: ID_VENDOR_ID=058f
```

and

```
udevadm info --query=all --name=/dev/sde | grep 6387
E: ID_MODEL_ID=6387
```

Is there a faster, better way to see devices by model/vendor when an application specifies devices this way?

fdisk -l does not show these udev infos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your `usb.ids` is outdated. No idea what your distro is but this file is normally stored somewhere in `/usr/share` and you can safely update it from the Internet: http://www.linux-usb.org/usb.ids

```
058f: Alcor Micro Corp.
    6387: Flash Drive
```